# Camera rotation in maze game depending of accelerometer

Tags: unity, c#, camera

I'm still newbie in Unity 3D... I'm trying to develop simple maze game. I want to roll my ball through maze, but I have to rotate camera left or right, otherwise the player can't see what's behind while rolling the ball on the left or on the right.

```
void Start ()
{
    offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
}
```

I'm using low pass filter for accelerometer values:

```
Vector3 lowpass()
{
    float LowPassFilterFactor = AccelerometerUpdateInterval / LowPassKernelWidthInSeconds;
    lowPassValue = Vector3.Lerp(lowPassValue, Input.acceleration, LowPassFilterFactor);
    return lowPassValue;
}
```

Accelerometer values are from -1 to 1 for each coordinate. Because of that I check my lowPassValue.x value and limit it. If it's positive ( >0.3 ), then the camera should turn right and if it's negative ( <-0.3 ) then camera should turn left.

```
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(45, Vector3.up* Time.deltaTime) ; // right
transform.rotation = rotation;

Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(-45, Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime) ; // left
transform.rotation = rotation;
```

But then my offset doesn't work anymore, I can't see ball anymore. And camera rotation doesn't work as it should. 
Is there any better solution for this or I'm using the wrong function?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: It would be easiest if you were controlling your camera using something as a lookAt matrix. I think Unity3D provides an interface for such, here: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html

Comment: @G.Rassovsky It doesn't work... Maybe I should rotate whole scene view somehow?